# Javascript parse JSON error, but works fine in validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

When I try to parse this JSON (Discord webhook):

````
{
  "content": "this `supports` __a__ **subset** *of* ~~markdown~~  ```js\nfunction foo(bar) {\n  console.log(bar);\n}\n\nfoo(1);```",
  "embed": {
    "title": "title ~~(did you know you can have markdown here too?)~~",
    "description": "this supports [named links](https://discordapp.com) on top of the previously shown subset of markdown. ```\nyes, even code blocks```",
    "url": "https://discordapp.com",
    "color": 16324973,
    "timestamp": "2018-12-18T09:22:12.841Z",
    "footer": {
      "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
      "text": "footer text"
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
    },
    "image": {
      "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
    },
    "author": {
      "name": "author name",
      "url": "https://discordapp.com",
      "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
    },
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "value": "some of these properties have certain limits..."
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "value": "try exceeding some of them!"
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "value": "an informative error should show up, and this view will remain as-is until all issues are fixed"
      },
      {
        "name": "<:thonkang:219069250692841473>",
        "value": "these last two",
        "inline": true
      },
      {
        "name": "<:thonkang:219069250692841473>",
        "value": "are inline fields",
        "inline": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
````

Using this code:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(req.body)
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

But if I use a website such as

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

To validate the JSON, it says the JSON is valid.
What is wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I'm using an express server to simulate discord server, so it sends web hooks to the express server instead, I get the JSON using req.body.

Comment: When you say when you used a website https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com
What does it mean?

Comment: it depends on your input of `JSON.parse()`,why not reproducing it use the editor on SO?

Comment: What is the output of: `console.log(typeof req.body)`? Also the variable containing your JSON string cannot be called `JSON` or JSON.parse would throw another error. The variable (whatever the name is) already contains an object and does not need to be parsed.

Comment: Minimal example: `JSON.parse({})`. Don't re-parse objects!

Comment: Please view the update.

Comment: For future reference, "Unexpected token o in JSON" is one of those magic messages that always means the same thing: you tried to parse an object as if it was a string.  Why? Because any basic object in Javascript, when converted into a string, looks like `"[object Object]"` - if you parse this as JSON, the `"o"` character is the first character out of place, hence the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `JSON` is a global object (it's the same object where you read the method `parse`!), so when you invoke `JSON.parse(JSON)` javascript thinks you want to parse it.

The same thing doesn't happen when you pass the variable to the validator, because it will be assigned to a local variable:

```
let JSON = "{}";

validate(JSON);

function(x) {
JSON.parse(x); // here JSON is again your global object!
}
```

---

**EDIT**

According to your updated question, maybe it happens because you already use `bodyParser.json()` as middleware, and when you use it, `req.body` is already an object and you don't need to parse it again.

Trying to parsing an already parsed object will throw an error.

Comment: @RookieNeedingHelp maybe it happens because you are using `bodyParser.json()`? In that case, `req.body` is already an object, so you can't parse it again

Comment: @RookieNeedingHelp req.body is already an object, you don't need to parse it. JSON.parse only works on strings so the object is coerced to string and trying to parse `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that it would parse it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like without using JSONStream:

```
http.request(options, function(res) {
  var buffers = []
  res
    .on('data', function(chunk) {
      buffers.push(chunk)
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString())
    })
})
```

For using it with JSONStream, it would be something like:

```
http.request(options, function(res) {
  var stream = JSONStream.parse('*')
  res.pipe(stream)
  stream.on('data', console.log.bind(console, 'an item'))
})
```

(OR)

Here is the Some Steps for this issue..

You Can use lodash for resolving this.

import the lodash and call unescape().

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let htmlDecoder = function(encodedStr){
    return _.unescape(encodedStr);
}

htmlDecoder(JSON);
```